# how to create binary tree class?

Tags: c++

how to correctly create a binary tree? i have an error in function `AddNode`. tree is not filled. `root`=NULL

i have class `Tree` with field `root` of type `Node`. then i call `AddNode` to recursively create nodes.

and desctructor don't work for `Node`s.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Node { 
public:
    Node() { 
        std::cout << "Node Constructor\n"; 
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        parent = NULL;
    };
    virtual ~Node() { 
        std::cout << "Node Destructor\n"; 
        Destroy();
    };
    void SetEngWord(std::string eng) { engWord = eng; }
    void SetRusWord(std::string rus) { rusWord = rus; }
    std::string GetEngWord() { return engWord; }
    std::string GetRusWord() { return rusWord; }
    Node* GetLeft() { return left; }
    Node* GetRight() { return right; }
    Node* GetParent() { return parent; }
    void SetLeft(Node* l) { left = l; }
    void SetRight(Node* r) { right = r; }
    void SetParent(Node* p) { parent = p; }
    void PrintWord() { std::cout << engWord << " - " << rusWord << std::endl; }
    void Destroy();
private:
    std::string engWord;
    std::string rusWord;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node* parent;
};

void Node::Destroy() {
    if (left != NULL) { left->Destroy(); delete left; }
    if (right != NULL) { right->Destroy(); delete right; }
    delete this;
}

class Tree {
public:
    Tree() { 
        std::cout << "Tree Constructor\n"; 
        root = NULL;
    };
    virtual ~Tree() { 
        std::cout << "Tree Destructor\n"; 
        root->Destroy();
    };
    void Add(std::string eng, std::string rus);
    void AddNode(Node* src, Node* parent, Node* n, bool left);
    Node* Search(std::string s);
private:
    Node* root;
};



void Tree::Add(std::string eng, std::string rus) {
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->SetEngWord(eng);
    n->SetRusWord(rus);
    AddNode(root,NULL,n,true);
}

void Tree::AddNode(Node* src, Node* parent, Node* n, bool left) {
    if (src == NULL) {
        src = n; 
        if (src->GetParent() == NULL && parent != NULL) {
            src->SetParent(parent);
            if (left) src->GetParent()->SetLeft(n);
                else  src->GetParent()->SetRight(n);
        }
        return; 
    }
    if (n->GetEngWord() < src->GetEngWord()) { 
        AddNode(src->GetLeft(), src, n, true); 
    }
    else  { 
        AddNode(src->GetRight(), src, n, false); 
    }
}

Node* Tree::Search(std::string s) {
    Node* n;
    n = root;
    while(true) {
        if (n == NULL) break;
        if (n->GetEngWord() < s) n = n->GetLeft();
        if (n->GetEngWord() > s) n = n->GetRight();
        if (n->GetEngWord() == s) break;
    }
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    Tree tree;
    tree.Add("a","aa");
    tree.Add("b","bb");
    tree.Add("c","cc");
    Node* n = tree.Search("b");
    if (n != NULL) n->PrintWord(); else std::cout << "NULL" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Invoking `delete` calls the destructor for that object. So Destroy and the destructor call each other in an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: You appear to pass `root` to `AddNode` by value, so that it does not update `root`, so you're building nothing. Have you tried writing simpler programs, like a linked list?

Comment: If you modify the src variable inside `Tree::AddNode` you aren't modifying the caller's variable (e.g. `root`). You're probably better off not trying to pass this using variables and access root directly inside AddNode.

Comment: Time to start `gdb` and take a look what’s happening, I guess. Before that (or in addition to that), run it under `valgrind` and make sure it reports zero errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
void Tree::AddNode(Node*& src, Node* parent, Node* n, bool left) {
    if (src == NULL) {
        src = n; 
        if (src->GetParent() == NULL && parent != NULL) {
            src->SetParent(parent);
            if (left) src->GetParent()->SetLeft(n);
                else  src->GetParent()->SetRight(n);
        }
        return; 
    }
    if (n->GetEngWord() < src->GetEngWord()) { 
        Node* nn = src->GetLeft();
        AddNode(nn, src, n, true); 
    }
    else  { 
        Node* nn = src->GetRight();
        AddNode(nn, src, n, false); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I see a few problems.

I would rewrite this method slightly:

```
void Tree::Add(std::string eng, std::string rus) {
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->SetEngWord(eng);
    n->SetRusWord(rus);
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = n;
    }
    else {
        AddNode(root,NULL,n,true);
    }
}
```

That will fix inserting the first element (when root is null).  Now you're destructors:

```
virtual ~Tree() { 
    std::cout << "Tree Destructor\n"; 
    delete node;
};
```

Your code didn't actually delete the node. Just let the node's destructor do the work.

This is a really bad idea:

```
void Node::Destroy() {
    if (left != NULL) { left->Destroy(); delete left; }
    if (right != NULL) { right->Destroy(); delete right; }
    delete this;
}
```

Objects shouldn't delete themselves. This causes no end of problem. This can be way, way simpler.

```
virtual ~Node() {
     delete left;
     delete right;
};
```

This works because if left is null, it won't hurt anything. If it points to something, we'll destroy it, which recursively goes down until it's done.